# Wordpress on Google Cloud VM

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I need to upload all the wordpress 4.9.6 files to a VM running Ubuntu on Google cloud. 
So far, I've been able to upload individual files via SSH and move them within directories on the server, but when it comes to upload a folder and subsequently moving them, I just can't.

Can someone please be lovely and help me?

Comment: This is pretty vague. What specific problem are you having? Do you need someone to tell you how to move a file from one directory to another? What commands are you running? Are you getting errors? What do the errors say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remote copy a whole folder with `scp`.

`scp -r user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo /home/user/Desktop/`

From man scp

`-r Recursively copy entire directories`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version control system as `git`, you can clone the repository to `google cloud`. [See this useful link](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible#setting_up_the_wordpress_project).

```
git clone https://github.com/yourgitaccount/worpress-project.git
```